# OpenVPN client as a gateway: Ping from server to client works, but gateway does'nt

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, gateway

I have a working OpenVPN server up and running on an OpenWRT router, and want to use an **OpenVPN client as a gateway** for some local machines that are connected to my router.

**What i have done / What already works:**

- On the OpenWRT router (`192.168.0.1`/`10.0.0.1`) i can ping to and ssh into the OpenVPN client (`10.0.0.6`).
- i have set up a new routing table named `tunnelpi1` (`/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` on the router):

```
#
# reserved values
#
128 prelocal
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
#
# local
#
#1  inr.ruhep
10  tunnelpi1
```

- I have configured the router to route the traffic of the local client (`192.168.0.217`) through the OpenVPN client `10.0.0.6`, by adding the clients ip to the `tunnelpi1` table and by setting the default routing for this table:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.0.217/32 table tunnelpi1
ip route add default via 10.0.0.6 dev tun table tunnelpi1
```

- on the local client (`192.168.0.217`) i can't ping to `8.8.8.8` anymore as soon as the route is added, and can ping to `8.8.8.8` again when i remove it. So it seems that the rule is doing something (other clients are not affected, which is good).
- The OpenVPN client (`10.0.0.6`) has a fully working internet connection (via its own `eth0`). `ping 8.8.8.8` works without any problems. Its default gateway is not the VPN (`tun0`) but its `eth0` interface, which is exactly what i want.
- On the OpenVPN client i enabled ip forwarding and added NAT rules via iptables to forward everything via `eth0`:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

**What doesn't work:
I expect the traffic of `192.168.0.217` be routed through `10.0.0.6`. But this seems not to happen. I can't ping anything as soon as the table rule is added.
I suspect that either OpenVPN is blocking something, or that the iptables settings on the openvpn-client are wrong.
I don't know how to proceed from here.

Any suggestions ?